# Returning Conditional Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

Complete SQL Server noob here. I'm not sure how to go about finding an answer to as I'm mostly not sure what to begin searching.

I have `BLOG` table in my SQL Server database that stores blog posts like so

```
ID Title                             DatePosted
-----------------------------------------------
1  Why Batman is Greater than Sup... 07/15/2017
2  10 Reasons Superman is the wor... 08/02/2017 
3  Sick of Metropolis? Move to Go... 08/03/2017
```

I have another relational table that stores blogs that users have Liked, i.e.,

```
UserID  PostID  DateLiked
-------------------------------
232413  2       08/03/2017
232413  1       07/30/2017
234285  2       08/03/2017
```

Now what I'd like to do is call a simple `SELECT *` on my `BLOG` table, but pass in a `UserID` as an argument to that query to determine if the Blog was liked by said user, so my Result set would look something like so.

Given User ID: 232413

```
ID Title                             DatePosted  IsLiked
--------------------------------------------------------
1  Why Batman is Greater than Sup... 07/15/2017  1
2  10 Reasons Superman is the wor... 08/02/2017  1
3  Sick of Metropolis? Move to Go... 08/03/2017  0
```

Is this possible in SQL Server/Database? Any tips or helpful reading is VERY much appreciated!

Comment: Why is `Sick of Metropolis? Move to...` has `IsLiked = 1` ? The post ID liked is 1 and 2.

Comment: ah, thank you @rcs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming DateLiked column is nullable.
I am casting result of case to bit because I think you want it as Boolean value.

Passing userId parameter as @paramUserId

```
DECLARE @paramUserId AS INT;
SELECT b.Id,
       b.Title,
       b.DatePosted,
       CAST(CASE WHEN sb.DateLiked IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1) AS BIT) AS IsLiked
FROM BLOG AS b
INNER JOIN storesBlogs AS sb ON b.ID = sb.PostID
WHERE sb.UserID = @paramUserId
```

Comment: Note: It should be `LEFT JOIN`, not `INNER JOIN` and the `WHERE` clause should be part of the join condition.

Comment: Have you tested your code? According to my understanding, if there's no related record in "like" table for this UserId, then the query result should be empty.

Comment: Yes result be empty if no user has relation to a blog

Comment: Put sb.UserId = @paramUserId as part of where or on condition should have no difference.

Comment: I like to specify to parameters in where clause.

Comment: @XihuaDuan There is a huge difference.Check this link [where vs join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)

Comment: Sorry for my inaccurate saying, I mean it will return empty result (recordset) or a result comprise of one record (if in biz logic, to like a blog allows only for once) as the where one for this very case.

Comment: BTW, I only talks about where and on, but not left join vs inner join.

Comment: I was replying on difference between where and on. If you want further discussion then transfer it to chat.

Comment: SELECT b.Id,
       b.Title,
       b.DatePosted,
       CAST(CASE WHEN s.UserId = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS BIT) AS IsLiked
FROM BLOG AS b
LEFT JOIN storesBlogs AS s ON b.ID = s.PostID

Comment: I would use left join only if PostID  in second table is nullable which I think is not a possibility .check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798020/when-to-use-left-join-and-when-to-use-inner-join)

Answer (score 1):

It's the result on sqlite3.

```
select a.ID, a.Title, a.DatePosted, case UserId when 232413 then 1 else 0 end IsLiked from BLOG a inner join LikeTable b on a.id = b.post_id;

2|10 Reasons Superman is the wor...|08/02/2017|1
1|Why Batman is Greater than Sup...|07/15/2017|1
2|10 Reasons Superman is the wor...|08/02/2017|0

select a.ID, a.Title, a.DatePosted, case UserId when 232413 then 1 else 0 end IsLiked from BLOG a left join LikeTable b on a.id = b.post_id;

1|Why Batman is Greater than Sup...|07/15/2017|1
2|10 Reasons Superman is the wor...|08/02/2017|1
2|10 Reasons Superman is the wor...|08/02/2017|0
3|Sick of Metropolis? Move to Go...|08/03/2017|0
```

No result satisfies the PO's requirement, but statement#2 worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,title,dateposted,0 as IsLiked from blog where id not in (select postid from user_liked where  userid =232413)
union 
select id,title,dateposted,1 as IsLiked from blog where id in (select postid from user_liked where  userid =232413)
order by  IsLiked desc 

Result -

id  title                              dateposted IsLiked

1   Why Batman is Greater than Sup...   2017-07-15 1

2   10 Reasons Superman is the wor...   2017-08-02 1

3   Sick of Metropolis? Move to Go...   2017-08-03 0
```