# What's the right kind of join?

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

Products

```
Id Integer
Name Character Varying(200)
```

Orders

```
Id Integer
Product_Id integer
Started Timestamp
```

I need to fetch all orders with the product id and name together.

I've tried using inner join like this:

```
select orders.id, orders.started, products.id, products.name
from orders inner join
     products
     on products.id = order.product_id
```

But it don't show some orders that have no product linked (service orders).
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use LEFT JOIN and when to use INNER JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798020/when-to-use-left-join-and-when-to-use-inner-join)

Comment: No.. i'm trying to develop a simple store as a self training atempt.

Comment: The expression order.product.id is probably giving you a compile error. It needs to be order.product_id

Comment: Yes.. just a tipo. I'm writing in one computer and testing it in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't always have elements on the second table, you should use the "left join" -> it will retrive all rows from the left table, even if the right table doesnt have a matching row.

Like this:

```
select orders.id, orders.started, products.id, products.name from orders 
left join products on products.id = order.product.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a LEFT JOIN on your Product table from the Orders table.

```
SELECT [Your Columns]
FROM Orders o
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Products p ON o.ProductID = p.ID
```

A left join will still retrieve all rows from Orders, and will retrieve the data from the Product table when there is a match. When there is no ProductID in the Products table, the data you're trying to pull from the Products table will simply be NULL.

Using an inner join requires that the column(s) joined on be present in both tables. For example, if you have a Orders.ProductID = 7, Products must have a row with ID = 7 otherwise your query won't return a row for that Order.