# Delete rows with null values mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to delete the rows with null values in the column
How can i delete it?

```
SELECT employee.Name, 
      `department`.NUM, 
       SALARY  
FROM employee  
LEFT JOIN `department`  ON employee.ID = `department`.ID  
ORDER BY NUM;
```

```
+--------------------+-------+----------+
|  Name              | NUM   | SALARY   |
+--------------------+-------+----------+
|       Gallegos     |  NULL |     NULL |
|       Lara         |  NULL |     NULL |
|       Kent         |  NULL |     NULL |
|       Lena         |  NULL |     NULL |
|       Flores       |  NULL |     NULL |
|       Alexandra    |  NULL |     NULL |
|       Hodge        |  8001 |   973.45 |
+--------------------+-------+----------+
```

Should be like this

```
+--------------------+-------+----------+
|  Name              | NUM   | SALARY   |
+--------------------+-------+----------+
|                    |       |          |
|       Hodge        |  8001 |   973.45 |
+--------------------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: What do you want to delete? Employee or department or both?

Answer (score 0):

If by deleting you mean that you don't want to see rows with `null` values in your table, you can use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

You use `INNER JOIN` when you want to return only records having pair on both sides, and you'll use `LEFT JOIN` when you need all records from the “left” table, no matter if they have pair in the “right” table or not.

You can learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798020/when-to-use-left-join-and-when-to-use-inner-join).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to delete, but to me it seems more like removing nulls from the result of select statement, if so use:

```
SELECT employee.Name, 
      `department`.NUM, 
       SALARY  
FROM employee  
LEFT JOIN `department`  ON employee.ID = `department`.ID 
WHERE (`department`.NUM IS NOT NULL AND SALARY IS NOT NULL) 
ORDER BY NUM;
```

Note: The parentheses are not required but it’s good practice to enclose grouped comparators for better readability.

The above query will exclude the even if the `NUM` column is not null and the `SALARY` column is null and vice versa